# How to use Nuxt 3 layout transitions with JavaScript hooks not CSS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, gsap, nuxt3

I’m looking to use JavaScript hooks in layout transitions in Nuxt 3 to create an advance layout transition with GSAP. However, there are no examples of layout transitions with JavaScript hooks in the docs.

Where/how should I write my layout transitions to make use of JavaScript hooks, similar to how they are used in the page transition example.

```
pages/some-page.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'custom-flip',
    mode: 'out-in',
    onBeforeEnter: (el) => {
      console.log('Before enter...')
    },
    onEnter: (el, done) => {},
    onAfterEnter: (el) => {}
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: You will get the html element within the callback function. Whatever you want to do there, you can do with the element. In `onEnter` you get a done function as second parameter, which you need to call, when your animation is over.

Comment: Thanks. Where does this callback function go? The example above is for pageTransitions, I'm curious how to do the same for layout transitions

Comment: Unfortunately, Nuxt does not currently support layout transition JavaScript hooks. This issue was also raised in April of this year, but there has been no official response. [#20263](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20263)